# Having trouble running nginx on EC2 instance

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, amazon-ec2

I installed Nginx with phusion passenger, but I am having trouble accessing the server. I am using the default configuration file, yet I never get a response from the server when I try to visit the IP address in my browser. On my server I can do :

```
curl 127.0.0.1
```

To get a response, but visiting the IP address in the browser always times out. I made sure port 80 was open by executing `sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT`, but nothing changed. I am using Ubuntu.

Comment: Please post the result of the command `netstat -tupan` as root.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Possible error-sources:

- You use the internal EC2 ip and not the public.
- You don't have any security policies set and you are hitting the EC2 firewall.
- iptables is not configured correctly, disable it until it works without.
- Nginx does not listen on the correct port. Use the default config.

Comment: The problem was that I did not have the security policies set correctly. To fix this, I had to go into my security groups and make one that has port 22 open, port 80 open, and port 443 open (HTTPS). You cannot change the security group of a launched instance, so I needed to make an AMI of my server, terminate the server, and then launch a new instance with a different security group. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: @Max u saved me!  Also you can add additional security groups without scrapping your server.  I added an additional sec group for http on port 80