# Freshly installed nginx not serving default page

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

I just installed nginx on a new ubuntu instance.  It looks like nginx is running, here are the processes:

```
root      2062  0.0  0.1  85868  1340 ?        Ss   01:13   0:00 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx
www-data  2063  0.0  0.1  86212  1768 ?        S    01:13   0:00 nginx: worker process
www-data  2064  0.0  0.1  86212  1768 ?        S    01:13   0:00 nginx: worker process
www-data  2065  0.0  0.1  86212  1768 ?        S    01:13   0:00 nginx: worker process
www-data  2066  0.0  0.1  86212  1768 ?        S    01:13   0:00 nginx: worker process
ubuntu    2120  0.0  0.0  10460   932 pts/0    S+   01:34   0:00 grep --color=auto nginx
```

Also here is sudo nstat -plnt

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1076/sshd       
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2062/nginx      
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1076/sshd       
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      2062/nginx
```

But when I go to my public ip address (I don't have any sites configured) my browser times out and the default nginx page is not displayed.

There are no errors in the nginx log and sudo nginx -t looks fine.  I followed some tuts to get it installed and started, but everyhthing says it should immediately serve the default homepage.

Here is what is in my /etc/nginx/sites-enabled

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html index.htm;

    server_name localhost;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}
```

Comment: you can check `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default`, if that file exist? if yes. open it, check where root folder located (usually on `/usr/share/nginx/html`). and then check if that location exist or not. because sometimes when nginx trying to create folder and files, it got permission denied

Comment: /etc/nginx/sites-available/default is there along with the index.html file at /usr/share/nginx/html - so everything looks good there.  The weird part is I don't get any response from the server at all (ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT).  I can ping the server tho

Comment: possible duplicate of [Having trouble running nginx on EC2 instance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16054407/having-trouble-running-nginx-on-ec2-instance)

Comment: Double Check that you have opt for "Allow HTTP Traffic, Allow HTTPS Traffic" options in instance or in firewall

Comment: for me "sudo iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT" helped...

Answer (score 11):

I had this problem after I set a new server up on Digital Ocean and followed their tutorial which included enabling Uncomplicated Firewall. But the tutorial didn't mention enabling http and https traffic, which you have to do!

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-ubuntu-20-04-server-on-a-digitalocean-droplet

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-firewall-with-ufw-on-ubuntu-20-04

```
sudo ufw allow http
sudo ufw allow https
```

Answer (score 10):

I too had same issue. And the solution was to add inbound rules to the instance's security group. Allow HTTP and HTTPS traffic in the security group.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If the above answers don't work, make sure that you have the default `/var/www/html` folder which contains the default index.html file.

**Reason:** What happens is that the default configuration file at the path: `/etc/nginx/sites-available` calls a default file from `/var/www/html/index.html` which if not present (possibly deleted) throws a not found error.

Fix:

- Make sure to add the default file (the name is usually: `index.nginx-debian.html` in Ubuntu)
- Completely remove Nginx and make a fresh installation. The fresh installataion will create the default file again and visiting localhost/ServerIP shall give the default Nginx Page.

This worked for me like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

Wow - what a mess!  This issue held me up for 4d so super big Thx to the community for posting answers.

I had this problem with GCP.  I could create a web instance that worked based on a previous image but when I tried to create the web instance from scratch (domain - VM instance - zone) I could not get to the nginx default page.  I kept getting:

```
This site can’t be reached
<domainname.ext> took too long to respond.
ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
```

Using the posts above it became clear that I needed to enable both http AND https traffic.  Then it was just a matter of editing the VM Instance and clicking the Allow HTTP traffic box under Firewalls

I guess the logic is that before you install your certificates all traffic is (by default) http traffic therefore both need to be allowed.

And they lived happily ever after

Answer (score 0):

For me problem was in http protocol i used. I go to https://myurl.com and don't see anything. I edit url to http://myurl.com with http protocol but Chrome send me to https://myurl.com again. I think I had a cache or a setting on the site that redirected to https every time.

It's better to check page with `curl` command in linux:

```
curl 'http://myurl.com'
```

or

```
curl 'https://myurl.com'
```

If you get the right html doc in first case you need to work on SSL and nginx config file.