# nginx default page not showing in a browser

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

I am a newbie to nginx. My problem is the default page is not showing on the browser even if nginx seems to be running.

My environment is bash ubuntu on windows.
I have installed nginx with realip module successfully, at least that is what it said on completion of installation.

Started `sudo service nginx start`
I checked in the task manager that nginx is running and it is.
I run `sudo netstat -plunt` on the bash it shows the following

```
/etc$ sudo netstat -plunt
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
```

Also did the following

```
/etc$ ps waux |grep nginx
root       164  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        Ss    2433   0:00 nginx: master pr
babbbsa+   171  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S     2433   0:00 grep --color=auto nginx
```

The default config in `etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default` rightly includes all the relevant config except that I commented the line with `[::]:80` following suggestions to resolve failing nginx run with port 80 already in use message. Namely : `(nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use))`

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        #listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.html index.htm;

        # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
        server_name localhost;
```

After running nginx on ubuntu I opened the browser to see the default page using localhost.  To be precise I used the following:

```
      http://localhost/
      also tried it with:
      http://localhost:80
      http://x.x.x.x    # where x.x.x.x is my IPv4adress
      http://x.x.x.x:80    # where x.x.x.x is my IPv4adress
```

In all cases, no error page or no default nginx welcome page is showing. Simply the page hangs with `waiting for localhost ...`  message on the status bar.

I have visited  [Freshly installed nginx not serving default page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30770172/freshly-installed-nginx-not-serving-default-page) and also here  https://serverfault.com/questions/726546/what-are-the-first-steps-to-debug-nginx-default-page-not-showing-on-fresh-ubuntu but the solution is given do not address my issue. Here [Having trouble running nginx on EC2 instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16054407/having-trouble-running-nginx-on-ec2-instance) it was discussed that the problem might be related to incorrectly set security policies. To fix this it was suggested that `" ... go into 'the' security groups and make one that has port 22 open, port 80 open, and port 443 open (HTTPS) .."` if this is a solution to my problem (not that I am not running nginx -on -ec2 instance but just in case if the issue is security I mentioned this to show that I have also seen this) how do I set my security group and open the ports? Note that I am working on windows bash ubuntu and if someone knows the solution to my problem please be explicit about how to go about addressing it.  Thank you!

Comment: most importantly, tell us what you did in the browser. Please edit your Q to show the URL you used to try and connect. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you shellter. I have edited my Q to reflect what I did in the browser.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not an nginx expert. E googled now and saw that `:80` is the correct default port (maybe there is another port for admin console). OR try `localhost:8080`? Good luck!

Comment: maybe also try `localhost:443` . Else read thru this : https://docs.eucalyptus.com/eucalyptus/4.1.2/shared/console_config_ssl_certs.html  Good luck.

Comment: I found out the answer from [**HERE**](http://qiita.com/matarillo/items/ae62b1af761823b645b6).  To resolve this edit  /etc/nginx/nginx.conf  and add line master-process off. 

`user www-data;
master_process off; # add this line
worker_processes 4;
pid /run/nginx.pid;`    For some details note on this see [**HERE**](http://nginx.org/en/docs/faq/daemon_master_process_off.html)